# instantiate class objects from array values in AS3

Tags: arrays, class, actionscript-3, object

Am trying to create new instances of classes in a loop where the class instance names have been defined in an array. how Do i turn the array values from string to objects? here's what i have written so far

`var tiles2:Array = new Array("e1", "e2", "e3", ...);`

```
for (var i = 0; i < tiles2.length; i++){
    if (i == 0){
        xPos = 18;
    }else if (xPos > 0 && xPos < maxGridWidth){
        xPos =+ xPos + objWidth + horGap;
        //trace(xPos);
    }else{
        xPos = 18;
        yPos =+ yPos + verGap + objHeight;
    }
    var this[tiles2[i]] = new tiles2[i];
    this[tiles2[i]].name = tiles2[i];
    this[tiles2[i]].x = xPos;
    this[tiles2[i]].y = yPos;
    tileArray[i] = this[tiles2[i]];
    addChild(this[tiles2[i]]);
}
```

This is where I have a problem `var mc = new tiles2[i];`. the desired output am looking is something like

```
var e1 = new e1;
e1.name = tiles2[i];
e1.x = xPos;
e1.y = yPos;
tileArray[i] = e1;
addChild(e1);
```

if you have a better procedure for doing this i will be glad if you can show me

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this...

```
// If tiles2[i] is a string that is the name of a class
var type:Class = getDefinitionByName(tiles2[i]) as Class;
var thing = new type();

// If tiles2[i] is a string instance name for an existing object:
var thing:DisplayObject = getChildByName(tiles[i]);
```

OR, perhaps you just need to change the line in question to this:

```
//var mc = new tiles2[i]; <-- line in question

//take out the var, and instantiate the proper class
this[tiles2[i]] = new e1();
```

Comment: `tiles2` is just an array I created that holds names of objects created on stage that are in my asset library. it is not the name of a class file

Comment: @NelsonSule - it's not clear what anything is in your code - this answer looks to me to explain what you're trying to do - Since it apparently isn't, I took a guess and added it to this answer.

Comment: Or he even might be meaning to `var tileClassname:String = getQualifiedClassName(this[tiles2[i]]); var tileClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(tileClassname) as Class; var newTile = new tileClass();`

Comment: @kaarto Thanks for responding. I have created assets on stage with linkage class names such as `e1, e2`, ... instead of writing a code that will create instances of each one by one, I am looking for a way easily automate this tedious process. So I created an array with the names of the assets `tiles2=["e1", "e2",...]`. Now, what i want to achieve is turning each string in the array to a variable name and a class identifier e.g `var e1 = new e1();` for all the values of the array

Comment: So those are linkage names? Then Andrew's first solution should work for you, did you test it?

Comment: Yes, He's method is what I was looking for. Thanks. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong. i keep getting this error `TypeError: Error #1064: Cannot call method global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName() as constructor`. my code resides in the main document class file. Or perhaps I didn't do my linkage right

Comment: I got it working. thanks guys for the help. I was actually doing something wrong.